# How to upload file with to box-api with objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, box-api

I use AFNetworking for network operations

So which is the right way to send request to the https://api.box.com/2.0/files/content?
Right now I receive HTTP//1.1 500 Internal Server Error

**Code**

```
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
NSString *boundaryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"rn-------------------------%.0frn", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
NSData *boundary = [boundaryString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kBoxNetFileUploadURLFormat];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[BoxNet attachAuthHeaderForRequest:request];

[request addValue:[BoxNet SHA1:content] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-MD5"];
[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=\"%@\"", boundaryString] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


[body appendData:boundary];

[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\folder_id\"" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[folderID dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:boundary];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; filename=\"%@\"; name=\"filename\"", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:content];

[body appendData:boundary];

[request setHTTPBody:body];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", body.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];


AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    completion(JSON, nil);
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *err, id JSON) {
    completion(JSON, err);
}];

[operation start];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was `Wrong boundary & parameters formatting`, request handling is the same.

Attaching the new code:

```
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.box.com/2.0/files/content"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[BoxNet attachAuthHeaderForRequest:request];

[request addValue:[BoxNet SHA1:content] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-MD5"];
[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

// add file body and filename
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data;filename=\"%@\";name=\"filename\"\r\n", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type:application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:content];

// folder id
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition:form-data;name=\"folder_id\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[folderID dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

I've solved my problem thanks to this article: [Objective-C Box 2.0 File Upload - Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564069/objective-c-box-2-0-file-upload-problems/)

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer ASIHTTPRequest for uploading files and POSTing form data,  it is very east to user and here is the [code sample.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229646/asihttprequest-upload-file)

Comment: The author was abandoned this library. So I don't want to use it since the author doesn't have the possibility to maintain it's code if there are problem in the future. Thank you.

Comment: Oh! Thank you for the info. I do not know about other libraries. Some experts here will help you then. :-)